# [class.prop]/(3.7) seems to be in contradiction with [class.prop]/(3.7.3). What am I missing?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

> A class S is a standard-layout class if it:

[[class.prop]/(3.7)](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.prop#3.7):

> - **has no element of the set *M*(S) of types as a base class**, where for any type X, *M*(X) is defined as follows.<sup>102</sup>
>   [Note: *M*(X) is the set of the types of all non-base-class subobjects
>   that may be at a zero offset in X. — end note]

From the highlighted sentence above we conclude that *M(S)* is empty if S is a union, simply because unions don't have base classes. For me this is in contradiction with [class.prop]/(3.7.3) below.

[[class.prop]/(3.7.3)](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.prop#3.7.3)

> - If X is a union type, the set *M*(X) is the union of all *M*(U<sub>*i*</sub>) and the set containing all U<sub>*i*</sub> , where each U<sub>*i*</sub> is the type of the *i* <sup>th</sup>
>   non-static data member of X.

Comment: `M(S)` is a set of types of non-base-class subobjects. The sentence you highlight in no way indicates that `M(U)` must be empty for a union `U`. What it says is that a class `S` that has a base class of type `B` where `B` is also a member of `M(S)` (e.g. `class S : public B { B b; };` ) is not standard-layout.

Answer (score 3):

I was wrong. See the answer by zygoloid [here](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/4217#issuecomment-696230480).

In attention to @GManNickG I'm reproducing below the answer by zygoloid to my issue in GitHub:

> The wording is correct as-is. Consider:
>
> ```
> struct A {};
> union U { A a; };
> struct B : A { U u; };
> ```
>
> Here, B is not standard-layout because M(B) contains A and B has A as
> a base class. M(B) is defined as U plus M(U), and M(U) is defined as
> A.
>
> So we need M(U) to be non-empty for M(B) to properly compute "the set
> of the types of all non-base-class subobjects that may be at a zero
> offset in" U, even though U itself can't have base class.